# In Redux: how to store data from initial html to store? initialState or dispatch?

Tags: redux, react-redux

We have a dillema.
Certain data arrives through a template to our initial `index.html` page.
We put it on the `window` and the want to place it in the store.

Right now, we have something like this (psuedoish):

```
class App ... {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setLoggedInUser(this.props.user);
        // setLoggedInUser is a dispatch prop
    }
}

<App user={window.user} />
```

option two is to just use initial state:

```
createStore(reducer, { user: window.user }, ...)
```

We had a lengthy discussion and can't agree if `initialState` is an anti-pattern or not.

Which is the correct way to implement this type of data loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think initialState is not intended for such use. I would probably initialize it in reducer:

```
userReducer(state=window.user, action) ...
```

But that is under assumption that window.user is constant. If it is floating kind of thing, than I would probably go dispatch way, but not in `componentDidMount`, but in piece of code immediately following `createStore`

Answer (score 1):

Using initialState when creating the store from bootstrapped data is the preferred way according to the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#arguments) (see #2).

When bootstrapping data this way, you never get in a state where you're waiting for the store to apply the dispatched action. Another bonus is that you don't dispatch an action that isn't in relation to something happening in the UI.

Comment: I read on several location @DanAbramov saying that initialState should be used only to load complete state from the server as a caching or state recovery. Not to load some data from the server.

Comment: I don't see how loading some data instead of all data is detrimental to either the user- or the developer experience.